# Export Permissions of OneDrive Library Folders

Tags: onedrive

How can I export a list with available permissions, ie, links - edit or view, specific people - edit or view, for OneDrive folders?

Comment: Windows doesn't really have anything that exists that does what you describe.  Instead of doing something that doesn't exist, what problem specifically, are you trying to solve?

Comment: We use OneDrive for Business during tax season to create folders for clients where they can submit their tax documents. I want to build an internal control to regularly review permissions to ensure there aren’t any mistakes in sharing.

Comment: You will have to create your own tool for that since as I said, a tool that creates a list of permissions for files within a folder, doesn't technically exist.  There are tools that will display the permission for a file, and you can recursively call that file in a script, but what you want is pretty specific.

Comment: Here are three articles, hope they could be helpful. [List sharing permissions on a DriveItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_list_permissions?view=odsp-graph-online), [List children of a driveItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_list_children?view=odsp-graph-online) and [List available drives](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/drive_list?view=odsp-graph-online).